# New Mainboard Z97-K and OS is only bootable with the usage a LiveCD

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint, bootloader, uefi

I have a new Mainboard, CPU, Ram for his PC - a Asus Z97-K

other components like PSU, SSD, HDD are taken from the old Bios based Core2Duo PC

The OS is Linux Mint 16 and the LiveCD also - there is no Windows OS

My Problem now is that I can't boot from die HDD directly only via a Linux LiveCD. There I only have to press "boot from local drive" an then I get to the Bootloader where I can boot like with a normal PC. Otherwise without the CD it skips directly into UEFI

The OS was preinstalled from the old PC, I thought UEFI Bootloader etc made these problems so I installed Linux Mint 16 on a free Partition again but nothing changed really changed - before the CD trick doesn't worked but this might be cause I don't tried it with every UEFI configuration. SSD is GPT formatted.

The trick with the CD only work on some UEFI settings. With some settings the Bootloader of the LiveCD has no Background (only Black no Mint Logo) and no option to boot from drive

Now the working settings are:

- Fast Boot: disabled
- Secure Boot->OS Type: Windows UEFI mode (other possible option is "Other OS" which doesn’t work)

CSM Settings are:

- Launch CSM: Enabled
- Boot Device Control: UEFI and Legacy OPROM
- Boot from Network Devices: UEFI driver first
- Boot from Storage Devices: Both, UEFI frist
- BOOT from PCI-E/PCI Expansion Devices: UEFI frist

Boot Order is:

- P1: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250G
- P5: LITE-ON COMBO SHC-48S7K
- disabled
- disabled

in EzMode there is also a UEFI start entry which a made from Linux in the List, sometimes this entry is doubled an kills the UEFI if I move it

Comment: Why don't you just disable Secure Boot since your distrubution unlikely even supports it. The reason its not working is because of Secure Boot is looking for Windows not Linux.  Of course since CSM is enabled you basically have done this and effectively disabled UEFI support

Comment: I forgot to mention that secure Boot is disabled - one of the first things I did

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rs0uzbdcl5gqrx7/2014-08-11%2020.57.40.jpg

Comment: Verify if your actually trying to boot the SSD using the EFI drivers that exist on it or if your falling back to legacy support.  Based on your listed options Secure Boot despite what you might think does not actually appear to be disabled.

Comment: How to verify that? I'm not able to mount the efi partition I created and there is no efi dir in /boot/ or in / even in the new installation which should support efi [linux Mint 16](http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_petra_cinnamon.php) - how to really disable Secure Boot?

Comment: How is located in motherboards manual; no EFI directory indicates legacy mode to me

Comment: I tried `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"` and it says legacy - In the motherboard manual there is no real Information about disabling Secure Boot. Only the thing where I linked the picture (Windows UEFI mode|Other OS)

Comment: I would be interested in whether you can get this to work, as I may be getting that sort of motherboard soon to fix my computer :-) . This question has some stuff on EFI support (try a newer Ubuntu distro, Mint stops at 14.04 currently I think so may be missing stuff): http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: @Wilf I managed to install it as described in my answere (which was deletet) using boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair